# ¿Cómo hago que los map markers se borren y solo queden los seleccionados?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Tengo un combo-box el cual al seleccionar una de las opciones en el mapa debería marcar distintos puntos, pero mi problema es que al momento de seleccionar una nueva opción del combo-box los puntos de la selección anterior no se eliminan sino que se quedan ahí. Intente crear una función para eliminarlos cada vez que cambia la selección pero creo que no lo hice bien porque aún no logro solucionarlo.

Dejo un par de imágenes de referencia.

[image: Esto es lo que se muestra en el mapa seleccionando una primera opción]

[image: Esto es lo que se muestra si selecciono una opción seguida de la anterior]

Como se ve, los puntos se acumulan pero no se borran al cambiar la selección.

```js
let map = L.map("map").setView([-36.7869979,-73.0982683],14);

//Agregar tileLayer mapa base desde openstreetmap
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);




//Iconos personalizados para map markers
var  verde = L.icon({
  iconUrl: '/img/verde.png',

  iconSize:     [60, 60], // size of the icon
  shadowSize:   [50, 64], // size of the shadow
  iconAnchor:   [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
  shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow
  popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
var  naranjo = L.icon({
  iconUrl: '/img/naranjo.png',

  iconSize:     [60, 60], // size of the icon
  shadowSize:   [50, 64], // size of the shadow
  iconAnchor:   [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
  shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow
  popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
var  rojo = L.icon({
  iconUrl: '/img/rojo.png',

  iconSize:     [60, 60], // size of the icon
  shadowSize:   [50, 64], // size of the shadow
  iconAnchor:   [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
  shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow
  popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
var  azul = L.icon({
  iconUrl: '/img/azul.png',

  iconSize:     [60, 60], // size of the icon
  shadowSize:   [50, 64], // size of the shadow
  iconAnchor:   [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
  shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow
  popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
var  morado = L.icon({
  iconUrl: '/img/morado.png',

  iconSize:     [60, 60], // size of the icon
  shadowSize:   [50, 64], // size of the shadow
  iconAnchor:   [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
  shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow
  popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});







//Abreviaciones PR, CV, JP, RA, RP
//descripciones combo box
function updateDescription() {
    var object = document.getElementById("comboBox").value;
    var descriptionDiv = document.getElementById("description");
    switch (object) {
      case "1":
        descriptionDiv.innerHTML = "<p>El Material es trasladado al Centro de Pretratamiento de la Comuna, donde es enfardado por parte de Recicladores Base de la Comuna para posteriormente ser valorizado para su reutilización en generación nuevamente de Papel, Cartones, Material de Construcción, Embalajes.</p>";
        break;
        case "2":
        descriptionDiv.innerHTML = "<p>Es retirado por una empresa externa, la cual procesa el vidrio, lo separa por colores para fundirlo y generar nuevas estructuras de vidrio.</p>";
        break;
        case "3":
        descriptionDiv.innerHTML = "<p>El Material es trasladado al Centro de Pretratamiento de la Comuna, donde es enfardado por parte de Recicladores Base de la Comuna para posteriormente ser valorizado para su reutilización en generación nuevamente de PET 1.</p>";
        break;
        case "4":
        descriptionDiv.innerHTML = "<p>que hacen con el aceite que reciclamos</p>";
        break;
        case "5":
        descriptionDiv.innerHTML = "<p>Las pilas retiradas son llevadas a disposición final, esto, ya que no es posible reciclarlas o reutilizarlas debido a su composición.</p>";
        break;
        default:
        descriptionDiv.innerHTML = "<p>Seleccione un punto de reciclaje para conocer tu aporte. ツ</p>";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("comboBox").selectedIndex = 0;

  function mapMarkers(){
    var object = document.getElementById("comboBox").value;
    switch (object) {
      case "1":
        //puntos de reciclaje
        L.marker([-36.79157, -73.08062], {icon: verde}, {id: "PR01"}).addTo(map);
        L.marker([-36.78241, -73.10576], {icon: verde}, {id: "PR02"}).addTo(map);
        break;
        case "2":
        //Campanas de Vidrio
        L.marker([-36.8011958427, -73.0928327219], {icon: morado}, {id: "CV01"}).addTo(map);
        L.marker([-36.7821537729, -73.1054401636], {icon: morado}, {id: "CV02"}).addTo(map);
        break;
        case "3":
        //jaulas PET 1
        L.marker([-36.79562, -73.08199], {icon: azul}, {id: "JP01"}).addTo(map);
        L.marker([-36.79205, -73.11484], {icon: azul}, {id: "JP02"}).addTo(map);
        break;
        case "4":
        //Puntos de Recoleccion de aceite
        L.marker([-36.79, -73.1139], {icon: naranjo}, {id: "RA01"}).addTo(map);
        L.marker([-36.78244, -73.10631], {icon: naranjo}, {id: "RA02"}).addTo(map);
        break;
        case "5":
        //puntos de reciclaje para pilas
        L.marker([-36.7916, -73.08056], {icon: rojo}, {id: "RP01"}).addTo(map);
        L.marker([-36.79708, -73.08723], {icon: rojo}, {id: "RP02"}).addTo(map);
        break;
        default:

    }
  }
  document.getElementById("comboBox").selectedIndex = 0;

  function eliminarMarcadores() {
    // Obtener todos los marcadores del mapa
    var marker = map.getMarkers();

    // Eliminar cada marcador del mapa
    for (var i = 0; i < marker.length; i++) {
      map.removeMarker(marker[i]);
    }
  }





//modalbox reporte
function openModal() {
    document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
  }
  function closeModal() {
    document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
  }
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    if (event.target == modal) {
      closeModal();
    }
  }
```

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
.left, .right {
  height: 100%;
}
.left {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 70%;
}
.right {
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
}
.card{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #b6b6b6;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 97%;
  width: 95%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.info{
  text-align: left;
}
#map {
  height: 100vh;
  width:100%;
  position: fixed;
}

/*ventana de reporte*/
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  text-align: left;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 40%;
}

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI="
    crossorigin=""/>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Visor puntos limpios</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
      <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="card">
        <h1>Puntos de Reciclaje</h1>
        <div onchange="mapMarkers()">
            <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" id="comboBox" onchange="updateDescription()">
            <option value="">Seleccione un punto</option>
            <option value="1">Puntos de Reciclaje</option>
            <option value="2">Campanas para Vidrios</option>
            <option value="3">Jaulas Pet 1</option>
            <option value="4">Depositos para Aceite</option>
            <option value="5">Depositos para pilas</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <p></p>
        <div id="description">
          <p>Seleccione un punto de reciclaje para conocer tu aporte. ツ</p>
        </div>
        <hr class="border border-primary border-1 opacity-75">
        <div class="info">
          <h2><center>Información</center></h2>
          <br>
          <h5 value="codigo">ID:</h5>
          <br>
          <h5 value="direccion">Dirección:</h5>
          <br>
          <h5 value="horario">Horario:</h5>
          <br>
        </div>
        <hr class="border border-primary border-1 opacity-75">
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
            <form>
              <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <select class="form-select" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
                  <option selected>Elija un Problema</option>
                  <option value="1">Contenedor lleno</option>
                  <option value="2">Punto Demasiado Sucio</option>
                  <option value="3">Contenedor en mal estado</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-floating">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="ID">
                <label for="floatingPassword">ID del punto</label>
              </div>
              <br>
              <button class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h6>Alguno de los puntos está lleno? Avísanos!!!</h6>
        <p></p>
        <div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="openModal()">Reportar</button>
        </div>
        <p></p>
        <p><small class="text-muted"><em>Tienes alguna duda de como ocupar el visor de puntos limpios, ve este <a href="https://www.google.com/">tutorial</a>.</em></small></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM="
    crossorigin=""></script>
   <script src="map.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Para poder ayudarte, debes mostrar un [repro] del problema en cuestión, _como texto, con formato_. Sin ver el código es difícil ayudarte.

Comment: Que tal si muestras el codigo en donde estás intentando borrar los puntos marcados al cambiar la selección?

Comment: @ferter3006 ahí puse la función que cree con js

Comment: ¿Es [esto](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238414/leaflet-how-to-add-a-marker-to-or-remove-it-from-a-leaflet-map) que se menciona en [gis.se]?

Comment: @padaleiana es parecido pero creo que no es lo mismo, ya que los puntos que se marcan en mi situación están vinculados a lo seleccionado en el combo-box, por ejemplo, al presionar la opción de puntos de reciclaje del combo-box se marca con verde los puntos disponible en los alrededores y la idea es que al cambiar a otra opción del combo-box se borren los puntos anteriores y marque las nuevas opciones en el mapa, es decir que funciona con mas de un solo punto cada seleccion del combo-box, quizá yo estoy formulando mal el código y no es viable tantos puntos una sola opción de un combo-box

Comment: A eso voy con un [repro] de tu código. Actualmente no se ve el código en donde mostrás los marcadores en el mapa. De hecho, podrías crear un _snippet_ (con el botón que indica `<>`) para que se pueda ejecutar tu código en la pregunta misma y visualizar "en vivo" el problema en cuestión. Recordá: no tooodo el código, sino lo _mínimo_ para reproducir el problema.

Comment: @padaleiana ahí modifique la publicación un poquito para que se muestre un poco mas de código, disculpa si no me sé expresar, es primera vez que estoy poniendo en practica lo que estoy aprendiendo, todo eso esta en el archivo js y quiero intentar meter la función para eliminar los puntos al cambiar de una opción a otra

Comment: Agrega todo tu código HTML, JS, CSS, para poder replicar tu código y darte una mejor solución, recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta las veces que sean necesarias.

Comment: Pregunto... ¿Qué es _object_? Le estás agregando un eventListener, pero... ¿existe esa variable? De nuevo: agrega un [repro] (énfasis en _mínimo_) de tu código.

Comment: @AntonioGalicia ahi puse todo el codigo, lo que intento hacer es que al cambiar una selección del combo box se queden marcados solo un tipo de marcadores al mapa, pero se van agregando pero no se eliminan los anteriores, siento no poder resumirlo en menos código, no se como podría hacerlo en una pequeña escala para que no quede tanto código

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay muchas cosas que corregir en ese código, sin embargo solo tomaré (y corregiré) parte de él para abordar el problema principal, que es que no se eliminan los *markers*.

Para empezar: ¡`eliminarMarcadores()` nunca es invocada! Aún así, de ser invocada, en la consola se muestra el error

> TypeError: map.getMarkers is not a function

por lo tanto, o `getMarkers()` es una función que no está en el código de la pregunta (puede ser de una librería que no está allí, o el código fue copiado pero solo parcialmente, etc.), o que en definitiva no existe.

---

Los cambios hechos fueron los siguientes:

- Según se ve en el código original, según sea cada caso, se agregan allí dos *markers* al mapa. Para reemplazar este comportamiento, cada "dúo" fue movido a un [LayerGroup](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup)*.

```js
let puntosReciclaje = L.layerGroup([
        L.marker([-36.79157, -73.08062], {icon: verde}, {id: "PR01"}), 
        L.marker([-36.78241, -73.10576], {icon: verde}, {id: "PR02"})]);

let campanasVidrio = L.layerGroup([
        L.marker([-36.8011958427, -73.0928327219], {icon: morado}, {id: "CV01"}), 
        L.marker([-36.7821537729, -73.1054401636], {icon: morado}, {id: "CV02"})]);

let jaulasPET = L.layerGroup([
        L.marker([-36.79562, -73.08199], {icon: azul}, {id: "JP01"}),
        L.marker([-36.79205, -73.11484], {icon: azul}, {id: "JP02"})]);

let puntosRecoleccionAceite = L.layerGroup([
        L.marker([-36.79, -73.1139], {icon: naranjo}, {id: "RA01"}),
        L.marker([-36.78244, -73.10631], {icon: naranjo}, {id: "RA02"})]);

let puntosReciclajePilas = L.layerGroup([
        L.marker([-36.7916, -73.08056], {icon: rojo}, {id: "RP01"}),
        L.marker([-36.79708, -73.08723], {icon: rojo}, {id: "RP02"})]);
```

Luego, en un array se almacenan todos los grupos:

```js
let capas = [puntosReciclaje, campanasVidrio, jaulasPET, puntosRecoleccionAceite, puntosReciclajePilas];
```

- En la función `eliminarMarcadores()`, se obtiene cada grupo en el array denominado *capas*, con `foreach`, y se elimina a cada grupo del mapa con [removeLayer](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-removelayer):

```js
capas.forEach((capa) => map.removeLayer(capa));

// o lo que es lo mismo:
//capas.forEach((capa) => { map.removeLayer(capa) });

//o:
//capas.forEach(function(capa) { map.removeLayer(capa) });
```

- Así, en la función `mapMarkers()`, en cada `case` se va a agregar al mapa el grupo que corresponda:

```js
case "1":
    //puntos de reciclaje
    puntosReciclaje.addTo(map);
    break;
case "2":
    //Campanas de Vidrio
    campanasVidrio.addTo(map);
    break;
case "3":
    //jaulas PET 1
    jaulasPET.addTo(map);
    break;
case "4":
    //Puntos de Recoleccion de aceite
    puntosRecoleccionAceite.addTo(map);
    break;
case "5":
    //puntos de reciclaje para pilas
    puntosReciclajePilas.addTo(map);
    break;
```

- ¿Y cuándo se invoca a `eliminarMarcadores`? Cada vez que se modifica el valor seleccionado de *comboBox*:

```js
comboBox.addEventListener('change', () => {
  eliminarMarcadores();
});
```

<sub>* Esto fue sugerido [en este comentario](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413921/removing-previous-markers-when-new-markers-are-added#comment673005_413921) en [Geographic Information Systems](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).</sub>

---

Los cambios adicionales fueron:

- Como [se desaconseja usar manejadores de eventos *inline*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these), removí las referencias de `onchange` en el HTML y las pasé a JS. Así, el evento de cambio en JS queda de esta manera:

```js
comboBox.addEventListener('change', () => {
  eliminarMarcadores();
  updateDescription();
  mapMarkers();
});
```

- Se agregó el evento [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) para almacenar el `select` con id *comboBox* en la variable *comboBox* y agregar el evento de cambio a tal `select`, y se movió `document.getElementById("comboBox").selectedIndex = 0;` (que aparecía dos veces en el código) a este evento):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let comboBox = document.getElementById("comboBox");
    comboBox.selectedIndex = 0;
    comboBox.addEventListener('change', () => {
      eliminarMarcadores();
      updateDescription();
      mapMarkers();
    });
});
```

---

Finalmente, el código queda algo así como lo siguiente:

En el HTML, en el `div` que contiene los puntos de reciclaje:

```
<!--Nótese que los eventos "onchange" ya no están acá-->
<div>
    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" id="comboBox">
    <option value="">Seleccione un punto</option>
    <option value="1">Puntos de Reciclaje</option>
    <option value="2">Campanas para Vidrios</option>
    <option value="3">Jaulas Pet 1</option>
    <option value="4">Depositos para Aceite</option>
    <option value="5">Depositos para pilas</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Y en el JS (omitiendo la parte final relacionada al modal):

```js
let map = L.map("map").setView([-36.7869979, -73.0982683], 14);

//Agregar tileLayer mapa base desde openstreetmap
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);


//Iconos personalizados para map markers
var verde = L.icon({
  iconUrl: '/img/verde.png',

  iconSize: [60, 60], // size of the icon
  shadowSize: [50, 64], // size of the shadow
  iconAnchor: [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
  shadowAnchor: [4, 62], // the same for the shadow
  popupAnchor: [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
var naranjo = L.icon({
  iconUrl: '/img/naranjo.png',

  iconSize: [60, 60], // size of the icon
  shadowSize: [50, 64], // size of the shadow
  iconAnchor: [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
  shadowAnchor: [4, 62], // the same for the shadow
  popupAnchor: [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
var rojo = L.icon({
  iconUrl: '/img/rojo.png',

  iconSize: [60, 60], // size of the icon
  shadowSize: [50, 64], // size of the shadow
  iconAnchor: [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
  shadowAnchor: [4, 62], // the same for the shadow
  popupAnchor: [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
var azul = L.icon({
  iconUrl: '/img/azul.png',

  iconSize: [60, 60], // size of the icon
  shadowSize: [50, 64], // size of the shadow
  iconAnchor: [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
  shadowAnchor: [4, 62], // the same for the shadow
  popupAnchor: [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
var morado = L.icon({
  iconUrl: '/img/morado.png',

  iconSize: [60, 60], // size of the icon
  shadowSize: [50, 64], // size of the shadow
  iconAnchor: [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
  shadowAnchor: [4, 62], // the same for the shadow
  popupAnchor: [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});

let puntosReciclaje = L.layerGroup([
        L.marker([-36.79157, -73.08062], {icon: verde}, {id: "PR01"}), 
        L.marker([-36.78241, -73.10576], {icon: verde}, {id: "PR02"})]);
        
let campanasVidrio = L.layerGroup([
        L.marker([-36.8011958427, -73.0928327219], {icon: morado}, {id: "CV01"}), 
        L.marker([-36.7821537729, -73.1054401636], {icon: morado}, {id: "CV02"})]);

let jaulasPET = L.layerGroup([
        L.marker([-36.79562, -73.08199], {icon: azul}, {id: "JP01"}),
        L.marker([-36.79205, -73.11484], {icon: azul}, {id: "JP02"})]);

let puntosRecoleccionAceite = L.layerGroup([
        L.marker([-36.79, -73.1139], {icon: naranjo}, {id: "RA01"}),
        L.marker([-36.78244, -73.10631], {icon: naranjo}, {id: "RA02"})]);

let puntosReciclajePilas = L.layerGroup([
        L.marker([-36.7916, -73.08056], {icon: rojo}, {id: "RP01"}),
        L.marker([-36.79708, -73.08723], {icon: rojo}, {id: "RP02"})]);

let capas = [puntosReciclaje, campanasVidrio, jaulasPET, puntosRecoleccionAceite, puntosReciclajePilas];

//Abreviaciones PR, CV, JP, RA, RP
//descripciones combo box
function updateDescription() {
  var object = document.getElementById("comboBox").value;
  var descriptionDiv = document.getElementById("description");
  switch (object) {
    case "1":
      descriptionDiv.innerHTML = "<p>El Material es trasladado al Centro de Pretratamiento de la Comuna, donde es enfardado por parte de Recicladores Base de la Comuna para posteriormente ser valorizado para su reutilización en generación nuevamente de Papel, Cartones, Material de Construcción, Embalajes.</p>";
      break;
    case "2":
      descriptionDiv.innerHTML = "<p>Es retirado por una empresa externa, la cual procesa el vidrio, lo separa por colores para fundirlo y generar nuevas estructuras de vidrio.</p>";
      break;
    case "3":
      descriptionDiv.innerHTML = "<p>El Material es trasladado al Centro de Pretratamiento de la Comuna, donde es enfardado por parte de Recicladores Base de la Comuna para posteriormente ser valorizado para su reutilización en generación nuevamente de PET 1.</p>";
      break;
    case "4":
      descriptionDiv.innerHTML = "<p>que hacen con el aceite que reciclamos</p>";
      break;
    case "5":
      descriptionDiv.innerHTML = "<p>Las pilas retiradas son llevadas a disposición final, esto, ya que no es posible reciclarlas o reutilizarlas debido a su composición.</p>";
      break;
    default:
      descriptionDiv.innerHTML = "<p>Seleccione un punto de reciclaje para conocer tu aporte. ツ</p>";
  }
}

function mapMarkers() {
  var object = document.getElementById("comboBox").value;
  switch (object) {
    case "1":
      //puntos de reciclaje
      puntosReciclaje.addTo(map);
      break;
    case "2":
      //Campanas de Vidrio
      campanasVidrio.addTo(map);
      break;
    case "3":
      //jaulas PET 1
      jaulasPET.addTo(map);
      break;
    case "4":
      //Puntos de Recoleccion de aceite
      puntosRecoleccionAceite.addTo(map);
      break;
    case "5":
      //puntos de reciclaje para pilas
      puntosReciclajePilas.addTo(map);
      break;
    default:

  }
}

function eliminarMarcadores() {
  capas.forEach(function(capa) {
    map.removeLayer(capa)
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let comboBox = document.getElementById("comboBox");
  comboBox.selectedIndex = 0;
  comboBox.addEventListener('change', () => {
    eliminarMarcadores();
    updateDescription();
    mapMarkers();
  });
});
```

---

Para mostrar cómo quedó en la respuesta, se reemplazaron los íconos por unos que Leaflet provee en el ejemplo [*Custom Icons*](https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/). No olvidar bajar el zoom :)

```js
let map = L.map("map").setView([-36.7869979, -73.0982683], 14);

//Agregar tileLayer mapa base desde openstreetmap
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);


//Iconos personalizados para map markers
var verde = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png',
  iconSize: [38, 95], // size of the icon
  shadowSize: [50, 64], // size of the shadow
  iconAnchor: [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
  shadowAnchor: [4, 62], // the same for the shadow
  popupAnchor: [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
var naranjo = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-orange.png',
  iconSize: [38, 95], // size of the icon
  shadowSize: [50, 64], // size of the shadow
  iconAnchor: [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
  shadowAnchor: [4, 62], // the same for the shadow
  popupAnchor: [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
var rojo = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-red.png',
  iconSize: [38, 95], // size of the icon
  shadowSize: [50, 64], // size of the shadow
  iconAnchor: [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
  shadowAnchor: [4, 62], // the same for the shadow
  popupAnchor: [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
var azul = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png',
  iconSize: [38, 95], // size of the icon
  shadowSize: [50, 64], // size of the shadow
  iconAnchor: [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
  shadowAnchor: [4, 62], // the same for the shadow
  popupAnchor: [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
var morado = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-orange.png',
  iconSize: [38, 95], // size of the icon
  shadowSize: [50, 64], // size of the shadow
  iconAnchor: [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
  shadowAnchor: [4, 62], // the same for the shadow
  popupAnchor: [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});

let puntosReciclaje = L.layerGroup([
  L.marker([-36.79157, -73.08062], {
    icon: verde
  }, {
    id: "PR01"
  }),
  L.marker([-36.78241, -73.10576], {
    icon: verde
  }, {
    id: "PR02"
  })
]);

let campanasVidrio = L.layerGroup([
  L.marker([-36.8011958427, -73.0928327219], {
    icon: morado
  }, {
    id: "CV01"
  }),
  L.marker([-36.7821537729, -73.1054401636], {
    icon: morado
  }, {
    id: "CV02"
  })
]);

let jaulasPET = L.layerGroup([
  L.marker([-36.79562, -73.08199], {
    icon: azul
  }, {
    id: "JP01"
  }),
  L.marker([-36.79205, -73.11484], {
    icon: azul
  }, {
    id: "JP02"
  })
]);

let puntosRecoleccionAceite = L.layerGroup([
  L.marker([-36.79, -73.1139], {
    icon: naranjo
  }, {
    id: "RA01"
  }),
  L.marker([-36.78244, -73.10631], {
    icon: naranjo
  }, {
    id: "RA02"
  })
]);

let puntosReciclajePilas = L.layerGroup([
  L.marker([-36.7916, -73.08056], {
    icon: rojo
  }, {
    id: "RP01"
  }),
  L.marker([-36.79708, -73.08723], {
    icon: rojo
  }, {
    id: "RP02"
  })
]);

let capas = [puntosReciclaje, campanasVidrio, jaulasPET, puntosRecoleccionAceite, puntosReciclajePilas];

//Abreviaciones PR, CV, JP, RA, RP
//descripciones combo box
function updateDescription() {
  var object = document.getElementById("comboBox").value;
  var descriptionDiv = document.getElementById("description");
  switch (object) {
    case "1":
      descriptionDiv.innerHTML = "<p>El Material es trasladado al Centro de Pretratamiento de la Comuna, donde es enfardado por parte de Recicladores Base de la Comuna para posteriormente ser valorizado para su reutilización en generación nuevamente de Papel, Cartones, Material de Construcción, Embalajes.</p>";
      break;
    case "2":
      descriptionDiv.innerHTML = "<p>Es retirado por una empresa externa, la cual procesa el vidrio, lo separa por colores para fundirlo y generar nuevas estructuras de vidrio.</p>";
      break;
    case "3":
      descriptionDiv.innerHTML = "<p>El Material es trasladado al Centro de Pretratamiento de la Comuna, donde es enfardado por parte de Recicladores Base de la Comuna para posteriormente ser valorizado para su reutilización en generación nuevamente de PET 1.</p>";
      break;
    case "4":
      descriptionDiv.innerHTML = "<p>que hacen con el aceite que reciclamos</p>";
      break;
    case "5":
      descriptionDiv.innerHTML = "<p>Las pilas retiradas son llevadas a disposición final, esto, ya que no es posible reciclarlas o reutilizarlas debido a su composición.</p>";
      break;
    default:
      descriptionDiv.innerHTML = "<p>Seleccione un punto de reciclaje para conocer tu aporte. ツ</p>";
  }
}

function mapMarkers() {
  var object = document.getElementById("comboBox").value;
  switch (object) {
    case "1":
      //puntos de reciclaje
      puntosReciclaje.addTo(map);
      break;
    case "2":
      //Campanas de Vidrio
      campanasVidrio.addTo(map);
      break;
    case "3":
      //jaulas PET 1
      jaulasPET.addTo(map);
      break;
    case "4":
      //Puntos de Recoleccion de aceite
      puntosRecoleccionAceite.addTo(map);
      break;
    case "5":
      //puntos de reciclaje para pilas
      puntosReciclajePilas.addTo(map);
      break;
    default:

  }
}

function eliminarMarcadores() {
  capas.forEach(function(capa) {
    map.removeLayer(capa)
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let comboBox = document.getElementById("comboBox");
  comboBox.selectedIndex = 0;
  comboBox.addEventListener('change', () => {
    eliminarMarcadores();
    updateDescription();
    mapMarkers();
  });
});

/////////////////////

//modalbox reporte
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
  if (event.target == modal) {
    closeModal();
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.left,
.right {
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 70%;
}

.right {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
}

.card {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #b6b6b6;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 97%;
  width: 95%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.info {
  text-align: left;
}

#map {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}


/*ventana de reporte*/

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-align: left;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 40%;
}

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI=" crossorigin="" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Visor puntos limpios</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
      <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="card">
        <h1>Puntos de Reciclaje</h1>
        <div>
          <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" id="comboBox">
            <option value="">Seleccione un punto</option>
            <option value="1">Puntos de Reciclaje</option>
            <option value="2">Campanas para Vidrios</option>
            <option value="3">Jaulas Pet 1</option>
            <option value="4">Depositos para Aceite</option>
            <option value="5">Depositos para pilas</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <p></p>
        <div id="description">
          <p>Seleccione un punto de reciclaje para conocer tu aporte. ツ</p>
        </div>
        <hr class="border border-primary border-1 opacity-75">
        <div class="info">
          <h2>
            <center>Información</center>
          </h2>
          <br>
          <h5 value="codigo">ID:</h5>
          <br>
          <h5 value="direccion">Dirección:</h5>
          <br>
          <h5 value="horario">Horario:</h5>
          <br>
        </div>
        <hr class="border border-primary border-1 opacity-75">
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
            <form>
              <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <select class="form-select" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
                  <option selected>Elija un Problema</option>
                  <option value="1">Contenedor lleno</option>
                  <option value="2">Punto Demasiado Sucio</option>
                  <option value="3">Contenedor en mal estado</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-floating">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="ID">
                <label for="floatingPassword">ID del punto</label>
              </div>
              <br>
              <button class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h6>Alguno de los puntos está lleno? Avísanos!!!</h6>
        <p></p>
        <div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="openModal()">Reportar</button>
        </div>
        <p></p>
        <p><small class="text-muted"><em>Tienes alguna duda de como ocupar el visor de puntos limpios, ve este <a href="https://www.google.com/">tutorial</a>.</em></small></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM=" crossorigin=""></script>
  <script src="map.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

<sub>PD: No estaría demás leer: [¿Cuándo conviene utilizar var, let y const en ECMA Script 6?](/q/56116) y [var, let, const... o nada en Javascript](/q/106042).</sub>